# Remove onfocused in Imageview

Tags: android, gridview

Im currently using this following code for a gridview
with image view. I need some help guys. How do i remove the orange border when clicking the image view or how to disable the on click on image view? I added the code on xml but it is not working? I used the following code that makes the gridview into square one.

```
package com.rogcg.gridviewexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SquareImageView extends ImageView
{
    public SquareImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
    }
}
```

and set everything in xml

```
<com.rogcg.gridviewexample.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_shape"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set  **android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"** for GridView it will focused the grid field and not the Imageview itself.

or can try this one also

**android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" for your GridView**

Comment: still doesn't work dude. the second one also covers the whole grid with yellow.

Answer (score 0):

First, I see that you set your imageview's background with that "grid_shape" color (which I guess orange), and you set imageview's padding to 3dp. So unless you change your view's background, the orange "background" will remain.

Second, If you doesn't set a specific onClickListener to your imageview, it will not listen to your onClick method. And if you once set an onClickListener to it, I think you can just do the trick: setOnClickListener(null) to remove the onClickListener from your imageview.

See if that help.